# Get the value of a static property from a System.Type

Tags: c#, system.reflection, system.type

I have the situation that I am trying to access a static property that contains a singleton to an object that I wish to retrieve only by knowing its type. I have an implementation but it seems cumbersome...

```
public interface IFace
{
    void Start()
}

public class Container
{
    public IFace SelectedValue;
    public Type SelectedType;
    public void Start()
    {
        SelectedValue =  (IFace)SelectedType.
                         GetProperty("Instance", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).
                         GetGetMethod().Invoke(null,null);
        SelectedValue.Start();
    }
}
```

Is there other way to do the above? Access a public static property using a System.Type ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see what's particularly cumbersome about that - the property access part is just a single line of code. Compared with many situations where you have to go through lots of hoops with reflection, this is pretty simple.

Comment: It seems cumbersome to go from a PropertyInfo that has a GetValue(Object) to a Method to get the value. Although I couldn't understand why GetValue() required an Object?

Comment: Ah, missed that. No, you can just call `PropertyInfo.GetValue`. The reason `GetValue` takes an object is to allow for the target for instance methods.

Comment: It does seem cumbersome, error prone and difficult to test. That's because you are trying to use the singleton and service locator anti-patterns. If the static property is mutable, you have a global veriable, which is a coding 101 "no no" and I'd recommend a serious rewrite. If it's immutable, then just inject its value where required using simple DI, or an IoC container if required.

Comment: As an aside, it would have been easier to spot all the code if you'd formatted it to avoid horizontal scrolling...

Comment: @DavidArno, you have lost me! I believe the Instance property is immutable as it returns a _private statis ClassThatConformsToIFace_

eg.
`private static ClassThatConformsToIFace _instance;
     public static ClassThatConformsToIFace Instance
     {
        get
        {
           return _instance ?? (_instance = new ClassThatConformsToIFace ());
        }
    }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simplify it slightly by calling [`PropertyInfo.GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue.aspx) instead:

```
SelectedValue = (IFace)SelectedType
   .GetProperty("Instance", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
   .GetValue(null, null);
```

As of .NET 4.5 you could call `GetValue(null)` as an overload has been added which doesn't have the parameter for indexer parameters (if you see what I mean).

At this point it's about as simple as reflection gets. As David Arno says in comments, you should quite possibly revisit the design instead.